# D3- positioning of a tooltip using d3.mouse is not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to place a tool-tip on hover on the circle [Example](https://codepen.io/santhikumar43/pen/JjdMLOG)

There is a div on top of the SVG which has height to it, because of that div, the tool-tip position is incorrect.

Sample code.

```
.on('mousemove', function (d) {
  tooltip
    .html('No data to display.')
    .style('left', (d3.mouse(this)[0] + 20) + 'px')
    .style('top', d3.mouse(this)[1] + 'px')
  })
```

I can still do some thing like this `.style('top', (d3.mouse(this)[1] + 100) + 'px')`. This should work, because i know the height of the above div.

Is there any possibility to get the Y position without adding the height of the elements which are above to the SVG using d3.mouse() event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`d3.event`](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/a22c42db65eb00d4e369) instead:

```js
.on('mousemove', function(d) {
  tooltip
    .html('No data to display.')
    .style('left', (d3.event.pageX + 10) + 'px')
    .style('top', (d3.event.pageY + 10) + 'px')
})
```

With div:

```js
var a = [{
    cx: 40,
    cy: 60,
    r: 20
  },
  {
    cx: 120,
    cy: 80,
    r: 20
  },
  {
    cx: 200,
    cy: 60,
    r: 20
  }
];

const tooltip = d3.select('.tooltip')
var circle = d3.select("svg").selectAll("circle")
  .data(a)
  .on('mouseover', function() {
    tooltip
      .style('display', 'block')
    d3.select(this)
      .style('opacity', 1)
  })
  .on('mousemove', function(d) {
    tooltip
      .html('No data to display.')
      .style('left', (d3.event.pageX + 10) + 'px')
      .style('top', (d3.event.pageY + 10) + 'px')
  })
  .on('mouseleave', function() {
    tooltip
      .style('display', 'none')
  })

circle.exit().remove();

circle
  .attr('r', function(d) {
    return d.r
  })
  .attr('cy', function(d) {
    return d.cy
  })
  .attr('cx', function(d) {
    return d.cx
  })
  .style('fill', 'steelblue');
```

```css
.tooltip {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<div style="height: 100px;">Need this div</div>
<div class="tooltip"></div>
<svg width="720" height="120">
  <circle cx="40" cy="40" r="30" style="fill:steelblue;"></circle>
  <circle cx="80" cy="40" r="30" style="fill:steelblue;"></circle>
</svg>
```

Without div:

```js
var a = [{
    cx: 40,
    cy: 60,
    r: 20
  },
  {
    cx: 120,
    cy: 80,
    r: 20
  },
  {
    cx: 200,
    cy: 60,
    r: 20
  }
];

const tooltip = d3.select('.tooltip')
var circle = d3.select("svg").selectAll("circle")
  .data(a)
  .on('mouseover', function() {
    tooltip
      .style('display', 'block')
    d3.select(this)
      .style('opacity', 1)
  })
  .on('mousemove', function(d) {
    tooltip
      .html('No data to display.')
      .style('left', (d3.event.pageX + 10) + 'px')
      .style('top', (d3.event.pageY + 10) + 'px')
  })
  .on('mouseleave', function() {
    tooltip
      .style('display', 'none')
  })

circle.exit().remove();

circle
  .attr('r', function(d) {
    return d.r
  })
  .attr('cy', function(d) {
    return d.cy
  })
  .attr('cx', function(d) {
    return d.cx
  })
  .style('fill', 'steelblue');
```

```css
.tooltip {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<div class="tooltip"></div>
<svg width="720" height="120">
  <circle cx="40" cy="40" r="30" style="fill:steelblue;"></circle>
  <circle cx="80" cy="40" r="30" style="fill:steelblue;"></circle>
</svg>
```

Using `d3.mouse` with div:

```js
.on('mousemove', function(d, a, b) {
  tooltip
    .html('No data to display.')
    .style('left', (d3.mouse(this)[0] + d3.select('svg').node().getBoundingClientRect().x + 10) + 'px')
    .style('top', (d3.mouse(this)[1] + d3.select('svg').node().getBoundingClientRect().y + 10) + 'px')
})
```

```js
var a = [{
    cx: 40,
    cy: 60,
    r: 20
  },
  {
    cx: 120,
    cy: 80,
    r: 20
  },
  {
    cx: 200,
    cy: 60,
    r: 20
  }
];

const tooltip = d3.select('.tooltip')
var circle = d3.select("svg").selectAll("circle")
  .data(a)
  .on('mouseover', function() {
    tooltip
      .style('display', 'block')
    d3.select(this)
      .style('opacity', 1)
  })
  .on('mousemove', function(d, a, b) {
    tooltip
      .html('No data to display.')
      .style('left', (d3.mouse(this)[0] + d3.select('svg').node().getBoundingClientRect().x + 10) + 'px')
      .style('top', (d3.mouse(this)[1] + d3.select('svg').node().getBoundingClientRect().y + 10) + 'px')
  })
  .on('mouseleave', function() {
    tooltip
      .style('display', 'none')
  })

circle.exit().remove();

circle
  .attr('r', function(d) {
    return d.r
  })
  .attr('cy', function(d) {
    return d.cy
  })
  .attr('cx', function(d) {
    return d.cx
  })
  .style('fill', 'steelblue');
```

```css
.tooltip {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<div style="height: 100px;">Need this div</div>
<div class="tooltip"></div>
<svg width="720" height="120">
  <circle cx="40" cy="40" r="30" style="fill:steelblue;"></circle>
  <circle cx="80" cy="40" r="30" style="fill:steelblue;"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: It's working. Any idea about why it is not working with d3.mouse()? And is this correct way to use d3.event to get the position to display tool-tip?

Comment: that is because `d3.mouse` gives you position relative to the SVG's bounding rect and not the page's bounding rect. What you could do i calculate bounding rec of the whole svg and add its `x,y` values to your `left,top` style along with `d3.mouse` values

Comment: @Sam also note the shortcomings of `d3.mouse` when you scroll, example in the snippet. that too needs to be handled if used

Answer (score 0):

Quite useful:

https://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/mouse-position/

What you use depends on where the SVG is on the page, whether you will have scrolling and your Browser compatability needs.